# Access API tokens using Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm complete beginner at using API's, but I'm trying to exchange my secret for a JWT, using a Token endpoint.
(removed the `client_credentials` on purpose)

```
fetch('', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + key + '&client_secret=' + secret,
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "Bearer [JWT]",
    }
}).then(function (resp) {

    // Return the response as JSON
    return resp.json();

}).then(function (data) {

    // Log the API data
    console.log('token', data);

}).catch(function (err) {

    // Log any errors
    console.log('something went wrong', err);

});
```

I get this error:

> "token {error: "invalid_request", error_description: "grant_type missing"}"

Comment: Try something like `body: JSON.stringify({grant_type: client_credentials, client_id: key})`

Comment: Same error occurs

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the headers were wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code to correct your header section

```
 headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization":"Bearer [value of JWT Token]"}
```

- I am assuming that you are passing JSON as content.
- Also I am passing the JWT authorization token against Authorization Key.

Let me know if that works for you. Thanks.